How to visualize predicted samples using my code need more answers
How to visualize samples that are used to test models that have been created using a confusion matrix? For example as below.

you can visit GitHub, the whole thing is similar, just the architecture and dataset are different
https://github.com/cendekialnazalia/CaisimPestDetection/blob/main/Percobaan%20E%20-%20CNN%20add%20Models%20Xception.ipynb
this my code
Train model
epochs = 10

mc = ModelCheckpoint('sequential', monitor='val_accuracy', mode='max', verbose=1, save_best_only=True)  
early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=2)
history=model.fit(x=train_gen, epochs=epochs, validation_data=valid_gen)

def print_info( test_gen, preds, print_code, save_dir, subject ):
    class_dict=test_gen.class_indices
    labels= test_gen.labels
    file_names= test_gen.filenames 
    error_list=[]
    true_class=[]
    pred_class=[]
    prob_list=[]
    new_dict={}
    error_indices=[]
    y_pred=[]
    for key,value in class_dict.items():
        new_dict[value]=key             # dictionary {integer of class number: string of class name}
    # store new_dict as a text fine in the save_dir
    classes=list(new_dict.values())     # list of string of class names
    dict_as_text=str(new_dict)
    dict_name= subject + '-' +str(len(classes)) +'.txt'  
    dict_path=os.path.join(save_dir,dict_name)    
    with open(dict_path, 'w') as x_file:
        x_file.write(dict_as_text)    
    errors=0      
    for i, p in enumerate(preds):
        pred_index=np.argmax(p)        
        true_index=labels[i]  # labels are integer values
        if pred_index != true_index: # a misclassification has occurred
            error_list.append(file_names[i])
            true_class.append(new_dict[true_index])
            pred_class.append(new_dict[pred_index])
            prob_list.append(p[pred_index])
            error_indices.append(true_index)            
            errors=errors + 1
        y_pred.append(pred_index)    
    if print_code !=0:
        if errors>0:
            if print_code>errors:
                r=errors
            else:
                r=print_code           
            msg='{0:^28s}{1:^28s}{2:^28s}{3:^16s}'.format('Filename', 'Predicted Class' , 'True Class', 'Probability')
            print_in_color(msg, (0,255,0),(55,65,80))
            for i in range(r):                
                split1=os.path.split(error_list[i])                
                split2=os.path.split(split1[0])                
                fname=split2[1] + '/' + split1[1]
                msg='{0:^28s}{1:^28s}{2:^28s}{3:4s}{4:^6.4f}'.format(fname, pred_class[i],true_class[i], ' ', prob_list[i])
                print_in_color(msg, (255,255,255), (55,65,60))
                #print(error_list[i]  , pred_class[i], true_class[i], prob_list[i])               
        else:
            msg='With accuracy of 100 % there are no errors to print'
            print_in_color(msg, (0,255,0),(55,65,80))
    if errors>0:
        plot_bar=[]
        plot_class=[]
        for  key, value in new_dict.items():        
            count=error_indices.count(key) 
            if count!=0:
                plot_bar.append(count) # list containg how many times a class c had an error
                plot_class.append(value)   # stores the class 
        fig=plt.figure()
        fig.set_figheight(len(plot_class)/3)
        fig.set_figwidth(10)
        plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')
        for i in range(0, len(plot_class)):
            c=plot_class[i]
            x=plot_bar[i]
            plt.barh(c, x, )
            plt.title( ' Errors by Class on Test Set')
    y_true= np.array(labels)        
    y_pred=np.array(y_pred)
    if len(classes)<= 30:
        # create a confusion matrix 
        cm = confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred )        
        length=len(classes)
        if length<8:
            fig_width=8
            fig_height=8
        else:
            fig_width= int(length * .5)
            fig_height= int(length * .5)
    
        plt.figure(figsize=(fig_width, fig_height))
        sns.heatmap(cm, annot=True, vmin=0, fmt='g', cmap='Blues', cbar=False)       
        plt.xticks(np.arange(length)+.5, classes, rotation= 90)
        plt.yticks(np.arange(length)+.5, classes, rotation=0)
        plt.xlabel("Predicted")
        plt.ylabel("Actual")
        plt.title("Confusion Matrix")
        plt.show()
    clr = classification_report(y_true, y_pred, target_names=classes)
    print("Classification Report:\n----------------------\n", clr)

Confution matrix
print_code=0
preds=model.predict(test_gen) 
print_info( test_gen, preds, print_code, save_dir, subject ) 

output

I want to not only display the table output and recall, precision and f1 score values, but also display a visualization of each image predicted by CM, perhaps for example like the image above or it could be better.
for example in the "Daun Sehat"  table there is one data sample that is predicted to be "Karat Merah" but I don't know which image sample of "Daun Sehat"  is detected as "Karat Merah" if there is no visualization of that information
After the last line of code "make predictions on test set and generate confusion matrix and classification report" , I added code like the one below to find out the prediction for each test data
test_gen.class_indices

print(preds,preds.shape)

result_index = np.argmax(preds[])
print(result_index)

for i in range(len(preds)):
  if(np.argmax(preds[i]) == 0):
      print("Bercak Daun")
  elif(np.argmax(preds[i]) == 1):
      print("Daun Sehat")
  elif(np.argmax(preds[i]) == 2):
      print("Karat Merah")
  else:
      print("Lainya")

output
Bercak Daun
Daun Sehat
.
.
.
up to 177
Daun Sehat

instead of only displaying the Prediction with the string I also want to display it along with the image as well. Maybe there is a better and more efficient code for my problem?

https://github.com/cendekialnazalia/CaisimPestDetection/blob/main/Percobaan%20E%20-%20CNN%20add%20Models%20Xception.ipynb  If you want to see the entire code, you can visit GitHub, the whole thing is similar, just the architecture and dataset are different

It isn't really clear how you plot the confusion matrix, but you could iterate over preds or test_gen and plot the sample and output when their labels differ.
As you don't show the type of inputs you use for your model, the displaying method to use is up to you.
The code would look something like this :
# You should have before :
#   x_test : test dataset 
#   y_true : labels of x_test

y_pred=model.predict(x_test)

# First loop to sort falty predictions from correct ones
wrong_labels = []
for label, i in enumerate(y_pred) : # The array we iterate on doesn't matter, as they all are the same length
    if label != y_true[i] :
        wrong_labels.append([x_test, y_true, y_pred])

# Second loop to display errors, the limit to 4 samples is arbitrary

for x, y_true, y_pred, i in enumerate(wrong_labels) : 
    if i>=4 :
        break
    plt.subplot(1,4,i+1)
    display_sample(x)   # This function depends on the type of sample you have
    plt.title("Label " + str(y_true) + " expected, but predicted "+str(y_pred))

plt.show()


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

github.com/cendekialnazalia/CaisimPestDetection/blob/main/… If you want to see the entire code, you can visit GitHub, the whole thing is similar, just the architecture and dataset are different

thanks i got error sir can u help me explain why error and solved this
Cell In[26], line 8
6 wrong_labels = []
7 for label, i in enumerate(y_pred) : # The array we iterate on doesn't matter, as they all are the same length
----> 8     if label != y_true[i] :
9         wrong_labels.append([test_gen, y_true, y_pred])
11 # Second loop to display errors, the limit to 4 samples is arbitrary
IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type
